# $ \iint \sin(xy^{2}) dA $ above the annulus $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4 $

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate
$$ \iint \sin(xy^{2}) dA $$ above the annulus $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4 $

Without Polar Coordinates.

---

Attempt :

Since the region is symmetric, I can also calculate for just $1/4$ of it first. But notice that in the end I have to calculate

$$ \int \frac{ \cos(y^{2} \sqrt{4-y^{2}}) }{y^{2}} dy $$

If I change the order of integration I have to calculate

$$ \int \sin(xy^{2}) dy $$

How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: the integration domain is symmetry under $x \mapsto -x$ while the integrand picks up an minus sign....